# How do I find a substring in string and display its index using C?

Tags: c, string, substring

I am currently trying to find the substring of a string but also allow the user to choose whether they want it to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive. I realised that it is only reading the first letter of the match word.. I am not sure how to read the entire substring. I have just started learning C!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 255
char text[MAX_LENGTH], pattern[MAX_LENGTH], caseSelect;
char casesensitive;

int main(void) {
  printf("Text:\n");
  //scanf("%254[^\n]s", text);
  fgets(text, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
  //printf("%s", text);
    printf("Length of string: %d\n", strlen(text));
  
  printf("Match to:\n");
  fgets(pattern, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

  
  printf("Should match be case-sensitive?\n");
  scanf("%c", &caseSelect);

  caseSelect = toupper(caseSelect);
  
  if (caseSelect == 'N') {
    for(int i = 0; pattern[i]; i++){
      pattern[i] = tolower(pattern[i]);
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++)
      {
        char *position_ptr = strchr(text, pattern[i]);
        int position = (position_ptr == NULL ? -1 : position_ptr - text);
        printf("Matches at position %d.\n", position);
    break;
      }
  } else if (caseSelect == 'Y') {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++)
      {
        char *position_ptr = strchr(text, pattern[i]);
        int position = (position_ptr == NULL ? -1 : position_ptr - text);
        printf("Matches at position %d.\n", position);
    break;
      }
  } else {
    printf("No Matches.\n");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

You have another problem (I mean, besides the fact that it is searching individually each char of the pattern, instead of searching for the pattern, which is solved by usage of strstr) in your code: you are asking for the pattern with fgets.

But fgets includes the `\n` (Return) in the string. So, unless you are trying to match for the last word in your string, it won't work, since that '\n' won't be found.
You have to remove that `\n`. For example with `pattern[strlen(pattern)-1]='\0'`. Or using the `scanf` you have in a comment, instead of `fgets` at least for the pattern reading.

### Former answer

That is what `strstr` is made for

```c
    int ix;
    if(caseSelect!='N') ix=strstr(text, pattern)-text;
    else ix=strcasestr(text,pattern)-text;
    printf("Matches at position %ld.\n", ix);
```

Note: strstr return the pointer to the char of text that contains what is in pattern. For example:

```
text = "one two three";
pattern = "two";
```

if `text` is located at address `0x01234567`, then word "two" in in starts at address `0x0123456b`.
Then pointer arithmetic makes the subtraction between those two addresses = 4.

### Complete code

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 255
char text[MAX_LENGTH], pattern[MAX_LENGTH], caseSelect;
char casesensitive;

int main(void) {
  printf("Text:\n");
  //scanf("%254[^\n]s", text);
  fgets(text, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
  //printf("%s", text);
    printf("Length of string: %ld\n", strlen(text));
  
  printf("Match to:\n");
  fgets(pattern, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
  pattern[strlen(pattern)-1]='\0';

  
  printf("Should match be case-sensitive?\n");
  scanf("%c", &caseSelect);

  caseSelect = toupper(caseSelect);
  
  int position=0;
  if (caseSelect != 'N') position=strstr(text,pattern)-text;
  else position=strcasestr(text, pattern)-text;
  
  if(position>=0) printf("Matches at position %d.\n", position);
  else printf("No Matches.\n");

}
```

Comment: The part with the case-sensitivity is missing.

Comment: Yes indeed. But OP got that part right already. My point was not to give the entire code, but just the missing "codelet". But, just in case, I'll edit my post.